# How to add and store multiple objects in memory C#

Tags: c#

I have a WPF project where I need the user to enter in multiple modules which requires them to enter module code, module name, credits and hours for each module. I want to store each module with its specific details such as module1, module2, etc. What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: The traditional way to go is to use a database of some kind. Especially if your information needs to be used across multiple clients. Otherwise you could just write and read them from files

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, before you ask a question please conduct some research and read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: Simply create a list of objects with those properties and add as many as your user enters. To get a more specific answer, you need to provide more details on how the information is entered.

Comment: Really "in memory"? Mind that this means that data will not persist beyond termination of the app. If you start it again it's blank.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very basic example.

Start with a class called `Module`:

```
public class Module
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Credits { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Hours { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can write this code:

```
List<Module> modules = new List<Module>()
{
    new Module() { Code = "X123", Name = "How to Cheat at Coding", Credits = -1m, Hours = TimeSpan.Zero },
    new Module() { Code = "Y456", Name = "Read How to Ask", Credits = 1.5m, Hours = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3.0) },
};
```